# How to get Docker Swarm to apply changes to Compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

So, I'm running into an issue. Say you have a simple Docker Compose file like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: repo.hostname.com/web:latest
    environment:
      port: 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Then, I'd run the following command to apply it:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file path/to/compose.yml
```

Now, here's my problem. Once I've created the services via stack deploy, how do I UPDATE an existing service via the compose file?

If I just change the environment variable of "port" from "8080" to "8000" and rerun stack deploy with the new compose file, it doesn't pick up the change.

And, no, I can't use Kubernetes for reasons that are way out of the scope of this post.